# How to implement gating in neural network with Pytorch?

Tags: pytorch

In multi-task learning models (with a shared bottom and `K` different output tasks), during training, only one (or some) of the `K` tasks will be active given the input features of the training examples.

For example, I have a dataset of shopping history from male and female users, and I want to create a multi-task model with two different tasks: one predicting for males, the other for females.

```
     MLP (for male)                 MLP (for female)
            ⬆️                       ⬆️
                 MLP (shared bottom)
                         ⬆️
  training data features (gender feature = M or F)
```

The question is typically how we control the training so that for training data with `gender=M`, only the top-left branch is activated and learned, and for `gender=F`, only the top-right branch is activated?

Possible solutions would be:

1. Both branches are activated and create a mask to zero out male loss or female loss.

   This should guarantee that, during backpropagation, only one branch will have a gradient and weights will be updated.
   However, this wouldn’t be an efficient solution, wasting CPU/GPU doing useless computation for the other branch.
2. Manually control the forward/backward logic.

   That is, first run the training example through the shared bottom part, then check gender and decide which branch to run (like if-else code).
   But I don’t feel this is a good option.

Comment: I would say `2.` is your best option, why do you say it's not a good option?

Comment: Hey @Ivan, thanks for your opinion on this! Actually I just feel there could be even better/professional implementation for this purpose, and since I didn't see any real examples yet, so I'm not sure if it's good or not. Can you share some code examples or links to github repos?

Comment: The way PyTorch is implemented gives you lots of flexibility when constructing your modules. Having a conditional statement in your `forward` function doesn't pose much of an issue, not at all actually. I don't have a repo, on the top of my head, that does this. However, most complex training setup will have some custom logic in addition to the actual neural network definition. Note, your logic can be inside your module, or outside in a separate location, this is up to you.

Comment: @Ivan Yes indeed, we have the flexibility to do so. I'd also like to know how people typically do it :-) , thanks very much Ivan!